# uitableview cell delete, custom animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

i am trying to create a custom animation for the deletion of table rows by overriding the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths method. i created the custom insert animation successfully and tried to reverse the animation for the deletion part but i get some errors: Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] 
 
and 
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.(rows after update must be equal to rows before the update). 

If i don't override the deleteRows method and use tableView's default delete method, everything works fine, but not with my own method.

Here is the overriden method written in my tableViewController class:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
              withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
{

    [[super tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates]; // Populates UITableView with data
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        __block UITableViewCell *cell = [[super tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell) { // If indexPath isn't visible we'll get nil here
            // Custom animation
            CGRect frame = cell.frame;
            frame.origin.x = cell.frame.size.width;
            cell.frame = frame;
            frame.origin.x = 0;
            void (^animationsBlock)() = ^{
                cell.frame = frame;
            };
            if ([[UIView class] respondsToSelector:
                 @selector(animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:
                           initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:)]) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9
                                           delay:0
                          usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
                           initialSpringVelocity:0
                                         options:0
                                      animations:animationsBlock
                                      completion:NULL];
                 } else {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                           delay:0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                      animations:animationsBlock
                                      completion:NULL];
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

**deleteRowsAtIndexPathsMethod:**

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
              withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
{

    [[super tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates]; // Populates UITableView with data
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        __block UITableViewCell *cell = [[super tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell) { // If indexPath isn't visible we'll get nil here
            // Custom animation
            CGRect frame = cell.frame;
            frame.origin.x = 0;
            cell.frame = frame;
            frame.origin.x = cell.frame.size.width;
            void (^animationsBlock)() = ^{
                cell.frame = frame;
            };
            if ([[UIView class] respondsToSelector:
                 @selector(animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)]) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9
                                           delay:0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                      animations:animationsBlock
                                      completion:NULL];
                 } else {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9
                                           delay:0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                                      animations:animationsBlock
                                      completion:NULL];
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** this code is inside a method, that runs whenever i modify a cell's object. I modify an object and save it to core data, then i retrieve all the updated objects using [self populateData], then i want to run the animations: delete the old cell and insert the new updated cell somewhere at the bottom of the tableView

```
[coreDataStack saveContext];
[self populateData];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];

int oldIndex = indexPath.row;
int newIndex = newIndexPath.row;
if(oldIndex<newIndex){
    [self deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

} else if (oldIndex>newIndex) {
    [self deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

    [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

} else {
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Please show us the delete code

Comment: @HenriAsseily i edited my question and included extra code

Comment: I meant the overridden `deleteRowsAtIndexPath`. I have a hunch the problem is the position in the code of the call to `[super deleteRowsAtIndexPath]`

Comment: @HenriAsseily sorry my bad i forgot the most important code, added it now

Comment: why do you endUpdates before beginUpdates, and the method ends without a call to endUpdates? Also I would call `[super tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` as a completion to the UIView animation.

Comment: @HenriAsseily if i comment out the beginUpdates and endUpdate lines in the overriden deleteRows method, i don't see any delete animation, the cell just disappears, only the insert row animation is visible. i am not sure how to call `[super tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` as the completion of the animation

Comment: beginUpdates and endUpdates should be at start and end of your update code respectively. Make sure you they properly balance themselves out